# Cythonize python packages located in venv site-packages directory

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I have a private pip package located in my virtual environment site-packages folder and I'd like to cythonize it for a speed boost and added protection.

My script successfully converts the files to .c, however, it places the build/ folder for the temporary .so files locally. It then tries to copy those .so files locally to a folder that does not exist. Instead, I want it to copy those files over to the venv site-packages/ python package where it had just created the .c files.

Is there a way I can specify where to copy those files over?

Or can I specify where that build folder gets created?

```
my_app/ (working dir/main program folder)
    ├── app_gui/ (my application)
    ├── build/ (build folder generated by cython)

virtualenvs/lib/python/site-packages/
    ├── my_pip_installed_package/
        ├── folder/
```

```py
def main():
    all_files = get_all_files(BASE_DIR)

    py_files = [file for file in all_files if file.suffix =='.py']

    py_file_strings = convert_to_str(py_files)
    setup(ext_modules=cythonize(py_file_strings, compiler_directives={"language_level": "3"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what I would call a workaround to do this. Instead of running my cythonize script locally on the main application, I changed directories to the site-packages folder, changed where `BASE_DIR` points to and ran the script from there.